# Cannot use deserialized JSON for populating map - why?

Tags: apex, json, map, deserialize, serialization

I have deserialized some JSON into lists of objects:

```
Map<String, Object> Results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());        

List<Object> ValueLists = (List<Object>)results.get('values');

List<Object> FirstList = (List<Object>) ValuesLists[0]; 

String FirstString = String.valueOf(FirstList[0]);
```

All of that works fine. "ValueLists" looks like this, which to me looks like a list of lists:

```
((node-35351t9s_country_financial, system.devices.seen, 81859, 1578010220741491968), (node-35351t9s_country_financial, system.users.unique, 19494, 1578010220741550080))
```

But when I try to access the indexes of these lists to create a map, I get "Expression must be a list type: Object".

```
Map<Object, Object> ServerHostToUsers = new Map<Object, Object>();              
for(Object Obj: ValuesLists){
    ServerHostToUsers.put(Obj[0], Obj[1]);}
```

I can tell there is some sort of conversion from Object to String that I need, but I can't figure out why this won't work to populate the map, when accessing the indexes worked just fine for populating the lists before it.

Appreciate any nod in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At that point in your code, Apex only knows that `Obj` is an `Object`, because you told the compiler that `Obj` is an `Object`, but not a `List`. You'll need to do some casting to get this to work:

```
for(Object Obj: ValuesLists){
    List<Object> parts = (List<Object>)Obj;
    ServerHostToUsers.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fox, I was just a line away and that was it. Just realized that it was working in the previous code because those variables were declared as lists.